# Angular JS - How to detect dual binding finished?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the jquery "tableHeadFixer" library to fix the header and columns of a table. This works fine when we executing the below statement, after document ready or angular element ready function.

```
$("#customer-table").tableHeadFixer({ left: 2, right: 0, 'z-index': 0 });
```

Currently, I am using angular scope variable and ng-repeat to build the table rows. However, table data changes when there is a change in scope (search or sort). And table fixed headers need to recall again in order to prevent the previous functionality. So I am looking for a help to get the digestion completion notification when there are any scope variable changes along with its view rendering.

Comment: If the question is about Angular 2,4,5, please use only the `angular` tag, for Angular 1.x.x use only `angularjs`, with both tags it's entirely unclear what your question is about.

Comment: I've tried many ways to do it, But finally ended up with $timeout.